# How Add A Var To An Activity That Start From A Search

Tags: android, search

how can I add a var to an activity that start after a search?

I need to pass the DB adapter to this activity that will show the result of a search.

Thanks.

```
public class Search extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}

private void doMySearch(String query) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String query;
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific.

From what I understood, if you start your activity using startActivity(myIntent);

you should take a look at on putExtra methods from Intent class to add data to your activity

Comment: Ok, but where? There is no code to manage this activity. Everything is done by xml.